# Arduino Master - Slave setup

Tags: arduino, i2c, arduino-uno, arduino-yun

The master board is a Arduino Uno and the slave is a Arduino Yun. I have them both wired up using A4 & A5 of one board to attach to the A4 & A5 pin on the other. They are both powered separately but share the same ground like the diagram below.

[image: Board setup]

The code for both master and slave are below. If the slave board is not powered the master knows it can not talk to the slave and won't print out `Loop` until the slave is powered. This suggests that the master knows of the slave.

However the slave never receives this signal from the master. `receiveEvent` is never called.

I am doing this as I have ran out of pins on the master and want the slave to control a LCD display that takes up several pins as I'm sure you all know.

Any help would be great, thanks.

**Master**

```
#include <Wire.h>

#define SLAVE_ADDRESS 0x9

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); 

  Wire.begin();

  delay(1000);
}

void loop() {
    Wire.beginTransmission(SLAVE_ADDRESS);
    Wire.write('T');
    Wire.endTransmission();
    Serial.println("Loop");
    delay(1000);
}
```

---

**Slave**

```
#include <Wire.h>

#define SLAVE_ADDRESS 0x9

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); 

  delay(1000);

  Wire.begin(SLAVE_ADDRESS);
  Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent);

  Serial.println("Setup");
}

void loop() {
//  Serial.println("Loop");
}

void receiveEvent(int howMany){
  Serial.println("Receive event");

  while (Wire.available() > 0)
  {
    char c = Wire.read();
    Serial.println(c);
  }
}
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should think about the wiring.
Your Yun is using a different layout see: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=191974.0 
If the UNO is a R3 layout you can use the pins above AREF as far as I know. Check the exact pin-out of your Arduino(s).